# Conserving PVC that originates from the wall

Tags: plumbing

The sink's water valves are leaky and shall be replaced.  The are mounted on CPVC pipe that originates in the wall.  Fortunately, if the PVC is cut, there will be enough PVC protruding from the wall.

Is there a best practice, such that I can avoid losing pipe every time the valve must be changed out?  Fortunately this valve has provided service since 2004, so replacements frequency is approximately 15 years.

## UPDATE

[image]

The photos shows the front of the valve removed and was replaced with a new part.   Seems dry / water tight, while under pressure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install a threaded adapter on the CPVC, then use valves with threaded ports rather than solvent-weld style. The threaded connection can be made and undone many times before the threads should wear out. (image credit: pvcfittingsonline.com)

[image: PVC male adapter]

Answer (score 4):

Sharkbite push connectors work with CPVC and can be removed with a special tool if you ever need to replace the fitting.

Also, if the pipe is small enough you can buy compression fittings where you merely removed the compression stuff if you need to replace the fitting.

Comment: The special tool is a small C or U shape piece of plastic, so don't think special tool will mean costing money.

Answer (score 4):

If sticking with solvent-welded *(i.e there are perfectly good other answers here, this is **a** way, not **the** way)* you just stick on a coupling and a stub of new pipe **when** the old pipe gets too close to the wall.

Don't wait until **after** the old pipe *was* too close to the wall the *last* time you replaced the valve, though - you have to be proactive to save yourself pain this way.